# JsonPath query/expression

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

How to get values.status value when values.name.value=text from the json.

```
$.values[?(@.name[?(@.language=='EN' && @.value=='test')])].status
```

is giving more than 2 status values

```
{"values":[
           {"name":[{"language":"EN","value":"text"},
                   {"language":"DE","value":"text"}],
            "status":"active"},
           {"name":[{"language":"EN","value":"test2"},              
                    {"language":"DE","value":"test2"}],
            "status":"active"} 
           ]
}
```

Comment: At https://json-everything.net/json-path I'm not getting any results (also there's a space at the end of the path that's causing problems).  If I change `test` in your path to either `text` or `test2`, then I get the appropriate result.

Comment: I changed to- $.values[?(@.name[?(@.language=='EN' && @.value=='text')])].status. they get result like [
   "active",
   "active"
]